# How can I get the network-"Status" of an webelement?

Tags: java, selenium, networking, browser, status

i am using Selenium Webdriver on Java and I am trying to get the network status of every element with a network status like you can see in the image below.

Is there any way to get the status?

Edit:
I guess I cannot upload images. If you press F12 to open the dev-tools there is a network menu. If you click on it, the status of every webelement will show up there.

Comment: I think the mentioned image is missing.

Comment: are you looking for HTTP status?  `WebElements` aren't 1-1 with HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK DevTools and Networking tab controls are not natively supported by Selenium.